# PowerShell won't load LocalAccounts...sometimes

Tags: vb.net, powershell

So I write a lot of PowerShell automation scripts for users that aren't command-line people. To make things a bit easier, I'm trying to write a GUI launcher app in VB.NET. But I've hit a snag.

For a quick prototype app, I tried spawning PowerShell and running a simple script from my app. It failed because the PowerShell process I spawned refuses to load the LocalAccounts module.  Other modules, no problem. Just not that one. If I run PowerShell natively from the Windows shortcut it has no issues loading that module and accessing the cmdlets. The spawned process is executing the same EXE, using the same working directory, the PSModulePath variable is the same.

I don't want to proceed with this until I know why the spawned process won't load this module. If it can't load this one, what others might it fail to load? What would make a PowerShell process refuse to load the LocalAccounts module even though it's properly installed?

I'm developing on a Windows 10 workstation running PowerShell 5.1, Visual Studio 2017 & .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: How did you determine that it failed to load? Getting errors? Please paste the full error messages

Comment: Typical error message for not finding a module:

import-module : The specified module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts' was not loaded because no valid
module file was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ import-module Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts:String) [Import-Module],
    FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

Comment: Are any of the target workstations perhaps running an outdated version of Win10? My understanding is it didn't ship with Windows until 1607

Comment: Only the one workstation involved, but it's not a problem of the module not being available.  If I run PowerShell from the standard shortcut, the module loads with no problems.  I only run into problems when powershell.exe is spawned from within my VB app.